# My code works in Firefox but not Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

This code works fine in Firefox but IE9 returns an error of  '_area' is undefined

```
function dbasetype(){

    var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
    dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
    dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");


    if  (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")==-1) {
        _area.value = _dbase_name.value;            
    } else {
        setarea();
    }
```

After your responses I have now changed to code to this and it works. I can't figure out why it worked in Firefox without the definitions. I guess it carried them from the function that was calling this function?

```
function dbasetype(){

var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();
        dbasedata = dbasedata.replace(/\s/g, "");

var area = document.forms[0]._area;     
var _dbase_name = document.forms[0]._dbase_name;

if  (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")==-1) {
        area.value = _dbase_name.value;         
     } else { setarea(); }
     }
}
```

Comment: As the code you have supplied has no mention of _area until the  .value line, it's a bit difficult to work out why it's not working. Also, you're referencing _dbase_name once with a parent, and once without

Comment: In order to your other question. That seems to be wired. Normally the IE has global objects which are mapped to the ID and not the Firefox. Sure that you don't mixed up Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 0):

Where is `_area` defined?  Are you relying on the non-standard behaviour where `_area` is the ID of an element on the page? If so switch to `document.getElementById('_area')`

Comment: Well if it were a case of "_area" being the id of a page element, then it would work in IE but not Firefox ...

Comment: Is that the case? I couldn't remember which of the browsers did that... Still doesn't answer where `_area` is defined

Comment: Yes I agree, the problem is with "_area" somehow. Firefox is pretty stubborn about not doing the "implicit variable" thing with element id values; the webkit browsers act like IE. (I think it's a terrible mis-feature in IE that shouldn't be imitated, but that's just me. :-)

Comment: It turns out that I needed to define '_area'. It was defined in the function that was calling this function and worked in Firefox ok, strange. Bear in mind I have only been programming for a couple of weeks in the evenings :s

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concern, IE does not support `document.forms[]` array...